# Is it possible to `readFragment` from apollo cache if it has no id?

Tags: apollo-client, react-apollo

I have a nested component in my app.

At the top of the page, I have a query like

```
const REPOSITORY_PAGE_QUERY = gql`
  query RepositoryPageQuery($name: String!, $owner: String!) {
    repository(name: $name, owner: $owner) {
      ...RepositoryDetailsFragment
    }
  }
  ${REPOSITORY_DETAILS_FRAGMENT}
`;
```

`RepositoryDetailsFragment` then includes

```
// list of branches
refs(first: 2, refPrefix: "refs/heads/") {
  ...BranchesFragment
}
```

and finally

```
fragment BranchesFragment on RefConnection {
    totalCount
    pageInfo {
      ...PageInfoFragment
    }
    edges {
      node {
        id
        name
      }
    }
  }
  ${PAGE_INFO_FRAGMENT}
```

Obviously, I am not happy, because I need to pass `BranchesFragment` info around 3 levels deep.

Instead, it would be great if I could read it from the cache directly in my `BranchesList` component.
I tried to use

```
client.cache.readFragment({
   fragment: BRANCHES_FRAGMENT,
   fragmentName: "BranchesFragment"
});
```

But the problem is that this fragment does not have any id. Is there any way to deal with it and get the fragment info?

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I suddenly came to the solution. Maybe it could be useful for others.

Imagine we have a hierarchy of query -> fragments and components -> subcomponents like this:

**RootPageComponent**
query

```
query RepositoryPageQuery(
    $name: String!
    $owner: String!
    $count: Int!
    $branchSearchStr: String!
  ) {
    repository(name: $name, owner: $owner) {
      ...RepositoryDetailsFragment
    }
  }
  ${REPOSITORY_DETAILS_FRAGMENT}
```

component returns the following

```
<RepositoryDetails repository={data.repository} />
```

**RepositoryDetails**
Has a fragment

```
fragment RepositoryDetailsFragment on Repository {
    name
    descriptionHTML
    defaultBranchRef {
      id
      name
    }
    # the branches repository has
    refs(first: $count, refPrefix: "refs/heads/", query: $branchSearchStr) {
      ...BranchesFragment
    }
  }
  ${BRANCHES_FRAGMENT}
```

and returns `<BranchesList />` component.

So, instead of passing branch.info from `RootPage` to `RepositoryDetails` and then to `BranchesList`;

You can do the following in `BranchesList`

```
const client = useApolloClient();

client.cache.readFragment({
    fragment: BRANCHES_FRAGMENT,
    fragmentName: "BranchesFragment",
    id: "RefConnection:{}" // note this {} - apollow cache adds it when no id is present for the object
})
```

**IMPORTANT!**

Make sure to also update `type policy` for the field and set `keyArgs to []`

So in this particular case:

```
RefConnection: {
  keyFields: []
  ...
}
```

This will give the same result, but you won't have to pass props to nested components and instead can read from cache directly (just like one would do using redux)